# click on slideshow image to force just one step

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="divR">
<img class="imgT" src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="imgT" src="imgT/02.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="imgT" src="imgT/03.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="imgT" src="imgT/04.jpg" alt="img">
<img class="imgT" src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

css

```
.imgT{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

So I have a simple slideshow:

```
$(function(){
    $('#divR img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#divR :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
         .next('img').fadeIn(1000)
         .end().appendTo('#divR');}, 
      5000);
});
```

It works but I need to force executing this code by clicking on `imgT`, without waiting five seconds.

In other words - if there is no click slideshow should work as is, but if there IS a click it should execute just one step, i.e. change just actual picture with the next one, and then waiting the next click, if exists and so on...

Any idea, pls ?

Comment: You mean, you just want to have a standard carousel and no 5 seconds waiting?

Comment: @AndreaM16, I suppose it's standard carousel, but I need to force one img change with one click. After that click, if there is a next one - i t should change just one img again, but if there is no click, img should change after five seconds automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
$(function(){
    $('#divR img:gt(0)').hide();

    function next() {
        $('#divR :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
            .next('img').fadeIn(1000)
            .end().appendTo('#divR');
    };

    var interval;
    function start() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(next, 5000); 
    };
    start();
    $('img').click(function() {
        start();
        next();
    });
});
```